# Code signing a framework fails with "Permission denied" error

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, codesign

I've recently added the [Plantronics macOS SDK](https://developer.plantronics.com/softphone-integration-hub-sdks#macOSSDK) (Spokes3GSDK.framework) to my Electron desktop app.

When I attempt to sign the app, it fails with "Permission denied" error.

```sh
  ⨯ Error: Command failed: codesign --sign IDENTITY_HASH --force --timestamp --options runtime --entitlements ./setup/build/entitlements.mac.plist /private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MY_BRANCH/compile/mac/MY_APPLICATION.app/Contents/Frameworks/Spokes3GSDK.framework/Versions/A/Spokes3GSDK
/private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MY_BRANCH/compile/mac/MY_APPLICATION.app/Contents/Frameworks/Spokes3GSDK.framework/Versions/A/Spokes3GSDK: replacing existing signature
/private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MY_BRANCH/compile/mac/MY_APPLICATION.app/Contents/Frameworks/Spokes3GSDK.framework/Versions/A/Spokes3GSDK: Permission denied
```

I'm using `electron-builder` to build and sign my app so I've also created an issue [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5281). Though, the issue seems to be really caused by the `codesign` tool.

Comment: grant the write permission to file

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 filepath`

Comment: Thanks @tpikachu, I will try this but do you think it's safe to change the permissions? I mean I'm just using this SDK and not sure I'm not sure if I should mess with its files.

Comment: Sure it's safe. 777 means grant write and read permission to everyone.

Comment: So you can change this as your needs.

Comment: `u+w`? maybe this will be. I'm not sure the exact parameter but you can ask help from Google

Comment: `chmod u=wx` file        (Give the owner wx permissions)

Comment: please include the command you issued in your question?

Comment: It is already included `codesign --sign IDENTITY_HASH --force --timestamp --options runtime --entitlements ./setup/build/entitlements.mac.plist /private/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MY_BRANCH/compile/mac/MY_APPLICATION.app/Contents/Frameworks/Spokes3GSDK.framework/Versions/A/Spokes3GSDK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was that jenkins was copying the SDK files without changing the owner "root". So, a `sudo` was needed to make this command work.

I copied these files manually and put them in my repository (the owner of the file changed) and `sudo` was no longer needed.